# Pass AWS credentials to PigStorage function

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-pig, emr

How can I pass AWS credentials (aws_access_key and aws_secret_key) to PIG PigStorage function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't very explicit, and did gave an example of my use case, sorry. I needed that because I needed to use two different AWS access_keys, and using something like s3n://access:secret@bucket did not solve. I solved this changing the PigStorage function , storing in hdfs the results,  and on the cleanUpWithSucess method invoke a method that uploads the hdfs files to s3 with credentials. In this way I can pass the credentials to the PigStorageFunction when it is used to store, of course I also changed the constructor of the PigStorage to receive these arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Given this question is tagged with EMR I am going to assume you are using AWS EMR for  the Hadoop cluster.  If this is the case, then no further setup is required to access S3. The EMR service automatically configured Hadoop FS (which PigStorage will leverage) with either the AWS credentials of the user starting the cluster or uses the instance role requested.   Just provide the S3 location and  Pig will interface with S3 according to the policy and permissions of the user/role.

`A = LOAD 's3://<yourbucket>/<path>/' using PigStorage('\t') as (id:int, field2:chararray, field3:chararray);`